# mysql(mariadb) insert on duplicate update randomly works

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb, insert-update, jooq

I have insert on duplicate update methods like this, I use mariadb 10.1.14:

```
    public <R extends Record> void batchUpsertRecord(Table<R> table, List<R> records) throws PersistenceException {
        Connection conn = ConnectionPoolManager.INSTANCE.getConnection();

            try (DSLContext dslContext = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.MARIADB)) {
                List<InsertQuery> insertQueryList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (R record : records) {
                    InsertQuery<R> insert = dslContext.insertQuery(table);
                    insert.addRecord(record);
                    insert.onDuplicateKeyUpdate(true);
                    insert.addValuesForUpdate(mapOfChangedValues(record));
                    insertQueryList.add(insert);
                }
                dslContext.batch(insertQueryList).execute();
                conn.commit();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("Failed to upsert record into table({}).", table.getName(), e);
            } finally {
                ConnectionPoolManager.INSTANCE.closeConnection(conn, logger);
            }
    }
```

It randomly( and rarely) works if records already exists, if I delete the existing record, the insert always works.

From log I can see that sql has executed successfully every time, but most times Affected row is 1 even if records already exists(in update situation, it should be 2).

It seems updating not always working but insert does. If I manually execute the generated sql, it works normallly.

Really confused about this situation. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please show us the generated SQL statement(s), plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Closed this as a duplicate. The other, very similar question has more details.